# Redirect only root domain no subpages

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have tried some several possibilities to redirect only my root domain but unfortunatly i cant get it to work. These are the options that i have tried.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://newsite.com/folder/ [L,R=301]
```

Also tried this one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/folder/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Both codes redirect all my subpages for example: http://website.com/contact.html

Can anyone advise me what i might be doing wrong or missing anything.

Greets,
Roy

Comment: After clearing my cache it still redirects all my pages. Also tried on a new browser when never visited the site earlier.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldsite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/ [L,R=301]
```

this will only redirect `oldsite.com` to `newsite.com`
and not do anything for `oldsite.com/abc`

Comment: It still redirects all my other page too.
Might it have to do with any of these lines:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?queryString=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

No need to use mod_redirect, you can just use

[RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) "^/?$" "http://newsite.com"

in a `VirtualHost` for oldsite.com

Comment: Even with this added to my htaccess it still redirects all my pages.

Comment: you need to remove the other stuff. Also you need to make sure it is only used for oldsite.com